# Media Player start stop start

Tags: android, media-player

I am making a new android sound application. I made a clickable button to play sound when I click on it. But I also want it to stop playing sound when I click for the second time. That part works fine now here is the problem, when I click again on button to play sound again, it doesn't play it, Media player is completely stopped. I was looking on forums but I can't seem to find an answer that could help me.
Here is my Activity:

```
  MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1;
MediaPlayer mpButtonClick2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prvi);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spalshm);
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splashs);


    Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mpButtonClick1.isPlaying()) {
                mpButtonClick1.stop();
                mpButtonClick1.reset();

            }
            else {              
                mpButtonClick1.start();

            }


        }   

    });
```

When I try to write mpButtonClick1.prepare(); I get error Unhandled Exception Type IOE exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your class with below code:

remove `reset();`.

init well all components:

```
MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1;
MediaPlayer mpButtonClick2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prvi);

     mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spalshm);
     mpButtonClick2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splashs);


    Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mpButtonClick1.isPlaying()) {
                mpButtonClick1.stop();
             }
            else {              
                mpButtonClick1.start();
            }
         }   

    });
```

Comment: When I try this, I get "Unfortunately Splashzor has stopped. Error

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2atb96   here is the log cat. I wasn't sure how to post it so I took a screenshot.

Comment: it's not playing again after reset :(

Answer (score 21):

Try to use `pause` instead of `stop`.

Reason: if you pause the `MediaPlayer`, then you can resume it later. However, if you use `stop`, almost any other method won't work and you will have to prepare the MediaPlayer again (or create a new one).

[image]

More info: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

PS: don't forget to release the memory when you finish using the resources.

Comment: The clean answer, this should be on top. thnx

Answer (score 9):

Try this:
You should use only one mediaplayer object

```
    public class PlayaudioActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.far);
        mp.start();
        }

    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.beet);
        mp.start();
        }
    });
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: re-instantiating the player every time is what worked for me.  It's simple and no noticeable overhead .. thanks!

Comment: true lifesaver you are Thanks for this answer :)

Comment: @Rahul Glad, it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling mpButtonClick1.reset() after mpButtonClick1.stop() - don't do that:

```
if (mpButtonClick1.isPlaying()) {
    mpButtonClick1.stop();
    mpButtonClick1.reset(); //<--------- calling reset(), remove this line
}
```

The docs for [reset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset%28%29) say:

> Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state. After calling this method, you will have to initialize it again by setting the data source and calling prepare().

Remove mpButtonClick1.reset() and it should work.

Keep in mind that MediaPlayer works as a state machine, which means that if you call methods in the wrong order, you'll get problems. Please read about MediaPlayer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

Answer (score 2):

Hey please use following

for stop -> media player
   `mp.seekTo(0);
 mp.pause();`

again for start just call
 mp.start();

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when I need to play multiple times and I may need to stop one play to start another play, (like in the case of multiple buttons), I just create another player, making sure that I release the resources for the previous one. To stop just use

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
```

But for play use something like this (adapt the logging to your specific needs) to create/recreate your player:

```
private boolean createMediaPlayer()
{
    if (mediaPlayer!=null)
    {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=null;
        }

    }
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(Interop.PRIMARY_STREAM);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(m_soundFile);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        return true;
        // Interop.logDebug(TAG + "-loadAudio: SUCCESS" + m_soundFile);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Interop.logError(TAG + "-LoadAudio for Clic Sound: audioPlayer prepare failed for current file: " + m_soundFile);
        Interop.logError(TAG + "-Exception: " , e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and than use

```
if (createMediaPlayer())
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

this will ensure proper release of the resources used by the media player.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to Use pause instead of stop and the seek to the beginning of the song.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is quite old but recently while learning Android, I also got stuck at this point and found a very simple solution which I'd like to share with everyone.

Instead of trying to **stop** or **reset** the media, you can just **seek back** to the **starting position**.

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
```

For reference, I am also posting my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    public void play(View view) {
        mp.start();
    }

    public void pause(View view) {
        mp.pause();
    }

    public void stop(View view) {
        // this seeks to the beginning of the file
        mp.seekTo(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample_audio);
    }
}
```