# How can I use MediaPlayer for my button onClick?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onclicklistener

I'm doing an app in Android Studio. I have a problem because I can't put MediaPlayer to my buttons. When button will be pressed, the sound effect starts to play.

How can I use this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);
```

For my buttons onClick methods. When I put `mp.start();` in onClick Listener, my app crashes.

This is my code:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button3;
private Button entrycity;

private static final String NAME = "name";
private boolean isEnabled;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(onButton1Click);
    entrycity = findViewById(R.id.entrycity);
    entrycity.setOnClickListener(onButton2Click);


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    isEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(winflagi.IS_ENABLED, false);
    entrycity.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    if (isEnabled){
        entrycity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval);

    }
    else {
        entrycity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval3);
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener onButton1Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, flagi1.class));

    }
};

private View.OnClickListener onButton2Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, cities1.class));
    }
};

}
```

Comment: share crash logcat.

Comment: No sign of Media player in your code

Comment: Have you shared wrong code ?

Comment: Share the code where you are putting `mp.start();` and logcat error.

Comment: No, I am asking how to put mp3 to my button onClick

Comment: See this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464998/3022836](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464998/3022836)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Player start stop start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563729/media-player-start-stop-start)

Comment: From my logcat --> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: I still can't see `getResources()` and `mp.start`  inside your code. So either you are posting wrong code or incomplete code.

Answer (score 1):

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);

button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }
});

//here "R.raw.soho" is your music file
```