# Android MediaPlayer Usage Difference of "stop()" vs "release()"

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

I am learning how to play audio using `MediaPlayer` from this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/C_Ka7cKwXW0?t=261), which suggests using `release()` instead of `stop()` to **STOP** the audio. His explanation makes sense to me (`free up the system resource as soon as you don't need it`) and from a user perspective it works as expected, but I still feel like a bit weird that what's the point of using `stop()`? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20580149/3466808)

```
fun stopPlayer1() = mediaPlayer?.stop()

fun stopPlayer2() {
    mediaPlayer?.release()

    mediaPlayer = null
}
```

So, which approach is better? Release as soon as user stops the audio? Or release only when the screen is no longer visible (`onStop()` called)?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the diagram in [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#state-diagram)

`MediaPlayer` after `release()` is not "usable" anymore, you can `null`ify it safely. after `onStop` you still can call e.g. `prepareAsync()` and start playing again using single instance

edit: to comment

```
if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
```

Comment: So, which approach is better? Release as soon as user stops the audio? Or release only when the screen is no longer visible (onStop() called)?

Comment: well, thats uppon to you and your architecture. If you have in mind performance then it's always better to NOT create new instance if you can use existing one, but in this case won't be a big difference. "in theory" you should call `stop()` in `onStop()` and `release()` in `onDestroy()`, and create one instance in `onCreate`

Comment: be careful with `MediaPlayer`, read its doc, imho it's nasty class and API to handle. I'm always ending up with code added to answer for enshuring that I've released `MediaPlayer` "finally". these `try catch`es are for a reason...